# How do I set up my GDPR if I have more than one advertiser platform on a single domain?

Tags: advertising, gdpr

I work with ezoic ads and Google Adsense, so what should I do to set up my GDPR consent?

Should I ask both platforms to disable the consent and hire an authorized vendor to take care of the consent popup?

Comment: Have you considered Trustarc.com?  Although I suspect thats what you mean by authorized vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, any reason you recommend them? Thanks

Comment: I can't say I recommend them, it was a suggestion for you to look into, sorry.  I see them everywhere on sites so thought it might be something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your informative reply. I will check it on my own.